# GetLastInputInfo for MS Access Application

Tags: vba, ms-access, winapi

Is there a way to get the last input time like **GetLastInputInfo** from library user32.dll but only for a specific application (which has an **hWnd**)?, not for the session-wide as GetLastInputInfo actually does, I mean, for the application (MS Access in my case).

***Because I'm trying to close the MS Access Application after few minutes of inactivity, but I can't get this in a simple way.***

Actually, I can get the **GetLastInputInfo** and close Access after few minutes of complete user's inactivity (no keys pressed and no mouse movements), but it needs to be able to close its when user is using, for example, a internet browser and he has forgotten close the Access Application after 5 minutes.

It should be written using VBA.

I can check if user is using any Form inside the MS Access Application using this [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/access-vba/articles/detect-user-idle-time-or-inactivity). But it doesn't detect activity when user is typing on a textbox a long time, or when user is watching records for a while. I'm trying to do this in a "*elegant*" way, not writing a event handler on each controls on each form...

Comment: "*Is there a way to get the last input time ... for a specific applications (wich has an hWnd)?*" - not directly, no. You will likely have to resort to a system-wide message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to manually keep track of all input messages being sent around the system

Comment: Your example code compares current form and current control to previous values. To cover your "typing in a textbox for a long time" case, you could add the textbox Text property to that comparison (if it was a textbox). The case "when user is watching records for a while" would require them to at least be moving between records to detect anything (otherwise even mouse and keyboard hooks wouldn't help you) so you could also add the current form's current record ID or bookmark to the comparison to cover that case.